# React Native Youtube androidx.annotation.Nullable errors

Tags: react-native, youtube, androidx

I'm building a project on React Native 0.59.1 but when I add react native youtube I get the following errors when I run react-native run-android

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Task :react-native-youtube:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeView.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
>                             ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
>   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
>                             ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeView.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
>       @Nullable
>        ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeView
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void receiveCommand(YouTubeView view, int commandType, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
>                                                                      ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
>       public @Nullable Map  getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
>               ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setApiKey(YouTubeView view, @Nullable String param) {
>                                                ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropVideoId(YouTubeView view, @Nullable String param) {
>                                                     ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropVideoIds(YouTubeView view, @Nullable ReadableArray param) {
>                                                      ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropPlaylistId(YouTubeView view, @Nullable String param) {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropPlay(YouTubeView view, @Nullable boolean param) {
>                                                  ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropLoop(YouTubeView view, @Nullable boolean param) {
>                                                  ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropFullscreen(YouTubeView view, @Nullable boolean param) {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropControls(YouTubeView view, @Nullable int param) {
>                                                      ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:144: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropShowFullscreenButton(YouTubeView view, @Nullable boolean param) {
>                                                                  ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager
>   /Users/mattleach/Projects/EzeeTrader/EzeeTrader/node_modules/react-native-youtube/android/src/main/java/com/inprogress/reactnativeyoutube/YouTubeManager.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setPropResumePlay(YouTubeView view, @Nullable boolean param) {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol:   class Nullable
>     location: class YouTubeManager

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to your `gradle.properties`.

Then install jetify:

```
yarn add jetifier --dev
npx jetify
```

Then add jetify to your postinstall-Script on `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "jetify"
  ...
}
```

If you still have entries @ postinstall, only add them with `&&` at the end.
Example if you still would have `patch-package` in Postinstall: 
`„patch-package && jetify“`

At least, run `yarn install` to do the trick.

If you have trouble with jetify, you can undo changes in your node_modules-Package with `jetify -r`

Answer (score 0):

You must migrate to anroidx as the error log says. Try this.

**android/gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: What if I don't want to migrate to androidx

Comment: @EdisonBiba In the React-native 0.59 version, Android X is a must. If you don't want to use it, you should lower the React-native version.

Comment: Have you heard about jetifier and using it with -r option? I think that can be used